# Gnome Terminal broken after upgrading 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, gnome-terminal

The upgrade process was completed without errors (via Software Updater) but now I cant open gnome terminal. 
When trying to open it from xterm im getting the following message:

```
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

Then I find this error in syslog:

```
May  8 16:44:45 xxx dbus-daemon[5985]: [session uid=1000 pid=5985] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.160' (uid=1000 pid=21423 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real " label="unconfined")
May  8 16:44:45 xxx systemd[4291]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
May  8 16:44:45 xxx gnome-terminal-server[21426]: /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server: undefined symbol: vte_text_blink_mode_get_type
May  8 16:44:45 xxx systemd[4291]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
May  8 16:44:45 xxx systemd[4291]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May  8 16:44:45 xxx systemd[4291]: Failed to start GNOME Terminal Server.
```

Tried the following suggestions so far:

- locale reset
- adding a new user - cant open gnome-terminal there too
- remove/reinstall gnome-terminal

Comment: I have a similar problem. I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04.4 to Ubuntu 18 (bionic), and when I click on the right mouse button, it only shows: "change background", "Display Settings", "Settings". It does not have the menu item: "Terminal".
    

In "Activities", entering "terminal", it does not open the terminal - only XTerm or UXterm.   
In Journalctl, it says: systemd[1361]: Failed to start GNOME Terminal Server

Comment: I have this issue as well after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04

Answer (score 2):

Got the exact same problem (`Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached`) but `journalctl -xef` gave this error:

`/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server: undefined symbol: vte_text_blink_mode_get_type`

It was due to the [termite](https://github.com/thestinger/termite) installation which depends on [**vte-ng**](https://github.com/thestinger/vte-ng).

I fixed the problem by installing termite again with [this script](https://github.com/Corwind/termite-install/blob/master/termite-install.sh) and use `make uninstall` in both `termite` and `vte-ng` directories.

Maybe this can helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with **gnome-terminal-server** binary. It is looking for a function called *vte_text_blink_mode_get_type* coming from the **libvte** and did not find it.

Try to reinstall `libvte-2.91-0:amd64` and `libvte-2.91-common`

Comment: Tried it but still getting the same error

Comment: No idea. Try `sudo apt-get install -f` may be if something is missing ?

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f found 0 missing packages. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem, but it only occurs when I am connected via VNC. If I am logged in directly to the desktop, I do not see this issue.

When I was installing, there was some conflict with xrdp configuration. I chose to use my modified version instead of installing the version from the repository.